# Chain rule in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

In the following example from Chain Rule of Chapter 2 in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, I am confused about the dot after the first equality sign.
[image]

According to the chain rule, $D(g\circ f)(a)=Dg(f(a))\circ Df(a)$. How is the circle changed to the dot? How to interpret this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's multiplication. The chain rule was used.

Comment: Your second circle is actually a dot.

Comment: @GReyes No, except in dimension 1 it’s a composition of linear maps.

Comment: @TedShifrin Right, but such composition boils down to a dot product or a duality pairing.

Comment: @GReyes When we have $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$, I agree, but not otherwise.

Comment: @TedShifrin Agreed.

Comment: If those are matrices then that is a multiplication which corresponds to a composition of linear maps. For composition better use the d symbol which better refer recall about the linear map. In the picture he is using the representation in coordinates, hence matrix representation.

Comment: @TedShifrin I guess one can say it is matrix multiplication in coordinates in all cases.

Comment: @GReyes Of course, which is composition of linear maps in all cases. :) We just don't think of it that way when we do single-variable calculus.

Comment: Thanks, Prof. Shifrin. Appreciate that you are here to help the community even you are retired. I will read your book for sure. Maybe soon, if I can't move forward with Spivak's.

Answer (score 3):

The function $f$ is equal to $\sin\circ g$, with $g(x,y)=xy^2$. Therefore,$$f'(x,y)=\sin'\bigl(g(x,y)\bigr)\circ g'(x,y).$$But $\sin$ is a function from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$. So, the linear map $\sin'(x)\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is simply the multiplication by the real number $\sin'(x)\bigl(=\cos(x)\bigr)$. So, it's a dot that since it is simply a multiplication.